# H2O driverless AI deployment with Snowflake clarification?

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai, h2o.ai

I see Snowflake has a partner connect through which I could activate the H2O Driverless AI and access Snowflake from there.
I also see that H2O Driverless AI can be independently deployed on any cloud cluster, by we managing our own cluster instances.

How are both the clusters in above different?
In the H2O Driverless AI activated through the partner connect from Snowflake, don't we not require to manage the instances of H2O Driverless AI, so are we charged accordingly for that?

In the H2O Driverless AI deployed on our own Cloud cluster instances, is it the licensed version of H2O Driverless AI that we deploy and manage? Also, can we deploy the H2O-3(h2o flow) on these instances for building using h20 python packages, since i don't see any notebooks on Driverless AI for developing from ground-up?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the question, Roshan,

Snowflake Partner Connect enables a 14-day trial of Driverless AI to be started directly from the Snowflake UI.

When Driverless AI is deployed independently or in the H2O.ai Managed cloud it can connect to Snowflake using the Snowflake connector or JDBC.

Partner Connect is only for trials and labs that demonstrate the capabilities of the products. Customers would then pick a deployment (on-prem, cloud, managed cloud etc.) that aligns with your deployment requirements.

Both Driverless AI and H2O-3 can connect to Snowflake to access data for training, using the Snowflake Connector (https://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-10-lts/docs/userguide/connectors/snowflake.html) or JDBC (https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html#jdbc-databases)

When inferencing (scoring) models can be used with Snowflake as either external functions or user defined functions (https://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-10-lts/docs/userguide/snowflake-integration.html)

The functionality in Driverless AI can be used via an API, here is a link the describes how to use the client and notebooks (https://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-10-lts/docs/userguide/python_client.html)

Please reach out if you have any questions.